# How to keep "Save" and "Save as..." buttons work at the same time

Tags: c#, save

I have a program with 3 buttons: "Load", "Save" and "Save as".
The "Save" button is initially grayed out until you "Load" a file (or "Save as" a file in a better version).

"Load" uses a OpenFileDialog, "Save as" uses a SaveFileDialog, while "Save" reuse the openFileDialog.FileName property as argument for its StreamWriter.

The problem is, I can "Load" -> "Save" a file, but I can't "Load" -> "Save" -> "Save as", because "Save" method always uses openFileDialog1.FileName, but the current file being used is saveAsFileDialog.FileName, so it would keep saving on the previous file.

Tl;dr: I need to create a "string currentFileName" which gets updated after every "Load" and "Save as" operation, so that the "Save" method knows if the most recent file is the "Load" one or the "Save as" one. The problem is that I don't know how to create a variable inside my Form.cs that can be seen not just inside the main Form method, but also inside the methods generated by the event handlers of each control. I would need something like a global variable I think.

EDIT: code added.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void loadToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
                    {
                        string inputLine;
                        while ((inputLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            // some operations
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            // Enable "Save" Button
            saveToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;

            // currentFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName
        }

        private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName))
                {
                    // some operations
                }
            }

            // currentFileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName
        }

        private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // openFileDialog1.FileName should be replaced by currentFileName
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(openFileDialog1.FileName))
            {
                // some operations
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assumes that in your form, you handle events that fires your saving method(s). You need a class variable, indeed. Maybe show us the code you already have ?

Comment: Use a class level variable to hold the current name of the file. Also, you should probably show it to your client somewhere on the form.

Comment: You can add as many dialogs as you want (assuming this is windows forms) - ie 1 open and two saves.

Comment: I added the code. I would need to know how I can create that currentOpenedFile variable so that I  can use it wherever I want, so if someone can tell me where to exactly place the constructor instruction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this (please dont forget to add a second saveDialog):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
String pathName;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void loadToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
    pathname = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathname))
                {
                    string inputLine;
                    while ((inputLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        // some operations
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // Enable "Save" Button
        saveToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;

        // currentOpenedFile.FileName = openFileDialog1.FileName
    }

    private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
    pathname = saveFileDialog2.FileName;
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pathname))
            {
                // some operations
            }
        }

        // currentOpenedFile.FileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName
    }

    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // openFileDialog1.FileName should be replaced by currentOpenedFile.FileName
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pathname))
        {
            // some operations
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "Put the pathName string soon after the "public partial class Form1 : Form"" is all I needed to know, thank you.